# My local DNS don't resolv specific hostnames IP's

Tags: dns, bind

I've been trying to accomplish a DNS set up on my local machine using Linux and CentOS.

I've been following couple of tutorials and eventually everything seemed to work but when surfing to my example website I realized it didn't... This is what I've done after installing bind.

**named.conf:**

```
   zone "ims.be" IN {
            type master;
            file "example.com.zone";
            allow-update { none; };
    };
```

**example.com.zone:**

```
$TTL 86400
@    IN    SOA    localhost.    root.localhost. (
            42 ; serial
            3600      ; refresh after 6 hours
            900       ; retry after 1 hour
            1W     ; expire after 1 week
            1D )    ; minimum TTL of 1 day

@       NS      localhost.
        A       192.168.0.***
www     A       192.168.0.***
ftp     CNAME   www
```

**example.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    DocumentRoot /home/ims.be/
    ServerName ims.be
    ServerAlias www.ims.be
    ErrorLog logs/ims.be-error_log
    CustomLog logs/ims.be-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

I am able to ping, dig and nslookup to my example website called ims.be.

**PING**

[image: PING]

**DIG**

[image: DIG]

**NSLOOKUP**

[image: NSLOOKUP]

**NAMESERVERS**
[image]

But when surfing to ims.be or www.ims.be using Chrome/Firefox/IE/Safari I get an error that the webpage is not available... However when I surf to my IP address this displays the page ims.be like it should.

I'm working on a Windows 7 using CentOS to access Linux.

I discovered that I'm able to ping etc to ims.be from my Linux but when I'm in command line in Windows I'm unable to ping/nslookup/... ims.be:

> Ping request could not find host ims.be

I thought I had to change settings in Windows to get this done but nothing changed just yet... What I've done:

[image]

[image]

Comment: On your client box (Windows 7), do you have it set to use CentOS as a DNS server?

Comment: Compare what you've done to this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-bind-dns-server-on-centos-6

Comment: @SailorCire No, how do I set to use CentOS as a DNS server?

Comment: Looking at your updated question, you'll "never" be able to ping ims.be (this is due to your bind entries). Try pinging www.ims.be

Comment: also unable to ping www.ims.be...

Answer (score 1):

On the box you are using to try to reach the web page, what are your name servers set to?

If on Windows from a cmd prompt you can run:

```
ipconfig /all
```

If in Linux, your name servers should be in /etc/resolv.conf

Make sure they are set to only use your new name server.  By default, the system will search for the SOA (Start of Authority) and return whatever that server says is the correct IP.

To find the authoritative name servers for your domain you can do a whois, which reports the following as the authoritative name servers for the domain you listed:

```
Nameservers:
ns1.scartech.be
ns2.scartech.be
ns3.scartech.be
```

Comment: I've set these to my localhost and ims.be, edited above

Answer (score 0):

You can't ping from your Windows host to your Linux guest, Linux firewall is blocking the requests. Can you SSH from your windows into your Linux?

```
ssh user@ipadress
```

Make sure your ports are open (firewall is not blocking). For SSH you need port 22 to be open, for DNS port 53. You can open up ports like this.

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

Check the status of your iptables like this.

```
iptables -L -n
```

You can also try to manually add the IP of the Linux guest to your windows system. Go to

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

your Linux IP should be in there, if not, add it.

Comment: Yes I am able to ssh from windows to Linux. I opened port 53 but still not able to ping to ims.be...

Comment: Turn off your firewall on linux and see if you still can't ping. ' /etc/init.d/iptables save' and '/etc/init.d/iptables stop'. Then ping. To start again: '/etc/init.d/iptables start'

Comment: Thanks but still not able to ping

Comment: what's the return of 'traceroute 192.168.X.X -r' ? Also, try to manually add the IP of the Linux guest to your windows system. Go to C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file, your Linux IP should be there, if not add it.

Comment: Nice, I added the Linux IP manually and now it works! How's it possible this file doesn't get updated? Cheers!

Comment: using the right commands (i'm sure they exist, but I don't know them) that file would be updatet, I guess. Let me update my answer so you can accept and other ppl with similar problem can find out also.

Comment: Do not edit the hosts file! This is a bad precedent. Suppose he changes IPs or subnets, this defeats the purpose of a DNS server.